# Is there any alternative for Deptrac in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, dependency-management, clean-architecture

Deptrac is a static code analysis tool for PHP that helps you communicate, visualize and enforce architectural decisions in your projects. I want Something like this in Nodejs to be able to enforce my clean coding practices in Nodejs projects.

[image: https://qossmic.github.io/deptrac/]

Please do suggest, if you've come across any tools like this in nodejs environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [dependency-cruiser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-cruiser) in a few projects. So far it has been able to fulfill all my needs.